# How do main and article elements differ in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantics

My understanding is they both group content with `<article>` being suitable for content that can be syndicated, and `<main>` being suitable for content that is unique to a document. To me, they sound the same.

How do `<main>` and `<article>` elements differ?

Comment: Perhaps reading this page might clear a few things up: http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

Comment: Thanks, I can see very subtle differences such as `<main>` can be used only once in a document.

Comment: Yes, that's an important one but also it cannot be a descendant of `<article>` (among others) - In other words, `<main>` will always be a parent of `<article>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article: http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

There are two principal distinctions:

1. `<main>` can only be used once per document (`DOM`)
2. `<main>` cannot be a descendant of `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` elements

This means that `<article>` can be a child element of `<main>` (but not the other way around)

Semantically, this means that in one document (page) you will encounter a `main` section of the content of the page with (hopefully) 1+ `article`(s) within it.  In other words, the main article for this page.

You could also find 1+ `<aside>` section(s) with 1+ `article`(s) within.  Consider these other articles of interest on the page (but this is not the main content of the page)